# Extract hashtags from columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract, hashtag

i have a dataframe `df`. I want to extract hashtags from tweets where Max==45.:

```
Max    Tweets
42   via @VIE_unlike at #fashion
42   Ny trailer #katamaritribute #ps3
45   Saved a baby bluejay from dogs #fb
45   #Niley #Niley #Niley
```

i m trying  something like this but its giving empty dataframe:

```
df.loc[df['Max'] == 45, [hsh for hsh in 'tweets' if hsh.startswith('#')]]
```

is there something in pandas which i can use to perform this effectively and faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.str.findall`:

```
In [956]: df.Tweets.str.findall(r'#.*?(?=\s|$)')
Out[956]: 
0                  [#fashion]
1    [#katamaritribute, #ps3]
2                       [#fb]
3    [#Niley, #Niley, #Niley]
```

This returns a column of `list`s.

If you want to filter first and then find, you can do so quite easily using `boolean indexing`:

```
In [957]: df.Tweets[df.Max == 45].str.findall(r'#.*?(?=\s|$)')
Out[957]: 
2                       [#fb]
3    [#Niley, #Niley, #Niley]
Name: Tweets, dtype: object
```

---

The regex used here is:

```
#.*?(?=\s|$)
```

To understand it, break it down:

- `#.*?`  - carries out a non-greedy match for a word starting with a hashtag
- `(?=\s|$)` - lookahead for the end of the word or end of the sentence

If it's possible you have `#` in the middle of a word that is *not* a hashtag, that would yield false positives which you wouldn't want. In that case, You can modify your regex to include a lookbehind:

```
(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))#.*?(?=\s|$)
```

The regex lookbehind asserts that either a space or the start of the sentence must precede a `#` character.

Comment: Is there a way to get all hashtags in single list instead of multiple list in column? i am trying to use append or join but its not working.

Comment: @sparktime12 You call .values.reshape(-1,).tolist() on the resultant Series.