# Extracting @mentions from tweets using findall python (Giving incorrect results)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, twitter, mention

I have a csv file something like this

```
text
RT @CritCareMed: New Article: Male-Predominant Plasma Transfusion Strategy for Preventing Transfusion-Related Acute Lung Injury... htp://…
#CRISPR Inversion of CTCF Sites Alters Genome Topology &amp; Enhancer/Promoter Function in @CellCellPress htp://.co/HrjDwbm7NN
RT @gvwilson: Where's the theory for software engineering? Behind a paywall, that's where. htp://.co/1t3TymiF3M #semat #fail
RT @sciencemagazine: What’s killing off the sea stars? htp://.co/J19FnigwM9 #ecology
RT @MHendr1cks: Eve Marder describes a horror that is familiar to worm connectome gazers. htp://.co/AEqc7NOWoR via @nucAmbiguous htp://…
```

I want to extract all the mentions (starting with '@') from the tweet text. So far I have done this

```
import pandas as pd
import re

mydata = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/file.csv")
X = mydata.ix[:,:]
X=X.iloc[:,:1] #I have multiple columns so I'm selecting the first column only that is 'text'

for i in range(X.shape[0]):
result = re.findall("(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,25})", str(X.iloc[:i,:]))

print(result);
```

There are two problems here:
First: at `str(X.iloc[:1,:])` it gives me `['CritCareMed']` which is not ok as it should give me `['CellCellPress']`, and at `str(X.iloc[:2,:])` it again gives me `['CritCareMed']` which is of course not fine again. The final result I'm getting is

> [(' ', 'CritCareMed'), (' ', 'gvwilson'), (' ', 'sciencemagazine')]

It doesn't include the mentions in 2nd row and both two mentions in last row.
What I want should look something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve these results? this is just a sample data my original data has lots of tweets so is the approach ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) method to avoid the for loop, use *negative look behind* to replace `(^|[^@\w])` which forms another capture group you don't need in your regex:

```
df['mention'] = df.text.str.findall(r'(?<![@\w])@(\w{1,25})').apply(','.join)
df
#                                                text   mention
#0  RT @CritCareMed: New Article: Male-Predominant...   CritCareMed
#1  #CRISPR Inversion of CTCF Sites Alters Genome ...   CellCellPress
#2  RT @gvwilson: Where's the theory for software ...   gvwilson
#3  RT @sciencemagazine: What’s killing off the se...   sciencemagazine
#4  RT @MHendr1cks: Eve Marder describes a horror ...   MHendr1cks,nucAmbiguous
```

---

Also `X.iloc[:i,:]` gives back a data frame, so `str(X.iloc[:i,:])` gives you the string representation of a data frame, which is very different from the element in the cell, to extract the actual string from the `text` column, you can use `X.text.iloc[0]`, or a better way to iterate through a column, use [`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
import re
for index, s in df.text.iteritems():
    result = re.findall("(?<![@\w])@(\w{1,25})", s)
    print(','.join(result))

#CritCareMed
#CellCellPress
#gvwilson
#sciencemagazine
#MHendr1cks,nucAmbiguous
```

Comment: how can I select the first column from df? If iloc gives dataframe. I have multiple columns in my file and I have to process the first column only that is 'text'

Comment: To select the first column, you can either use the column name, i.e `df.text`, `df['text']` or use `iloc`, `df.iloc[:,0]`.

Answer (score 1):

While you already have your answer, you could even try to optimize the whole import process like so:

```
import re, pandas as pd

rx = re.compile(r'@([^:\s]+)')

with open("test.txt") as fp:
    dft = ([line, ",".join(rx.findall(line))] for line in fp.readlines())

    df = pd.DataFrame(dft, columns = ['text', 'mention'])
    print(df)
```

---

Which yields:

```
                                                text                  mention
0  RT @CritCareMed: New Article: Male-Predominant...              CritCareMed
1  #CRISPR Inversion of CTCF Sites Alters Genome ...            CellCellPress
2  RT @gvwilson: Where's the theory for software ...                 gvwilson
3  RT @sciencemagazine: What’s killing off the se...          sciencemagazine
4  RT @MHendr1cks: Eve Marder describes a horror ...  MHendr1cks,nucAmbiguous
```

This might be a bit faster as you don't need to change the `df` once it's already constructed.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try that as well :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mydata['text'].str.findall(r'(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))@.*?(?=\s|$)')
```

Same as this: [Extract hashtags from columns of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874879/extract-hashtags-from-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe), but for mentions.

- `@.*?` carries out a non-greedy match for a word starting
  with a hashtag
- `(?=\s|$)` look-ahead for the end of the word or end of the sentence
- `(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))` look-behind to ensure there are no false positives if a @ is used in the middle of a word

The regex lookbehind asserts that either a space or the start of the sentence must precede a @ character.